# Pairing (security) example for Seeed XIAO nRF52840

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf52, adafruit-circuitpython

I can't find example how to do BLE pairing with Seeed XIAO nrf52840 board. It doesn't matter to me if it will be Arduino or Circuitpython libraries. Is there something like this somewhere?

I would like to use this board for my project, but would like to ensure that anyone cannot read or change values in the BLE services.

My idea of use is that on the server side I select the device I want to pair with and on the device side I confirm the pairing manually e.g. with a button. From that point on, the server can then communicate with the unit and read or change its values.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With Arduino you could try this example: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_nRF52_Arduino/tree/master/libraries/Bluefruit52Lib/examples/Peripheral/pairing_passkey

I am actually trying to implement this feature as well. I was trying in CircuitPython, but I could not find a suitable way. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_BLE/issues/179), as there was nothing in their documentation to help.

UPDATE 2023-01-03 - In CircuitPython BLE security is not yet implemented, see answer to the [issue](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_BLE/issues/179) I opened.